# Update user_meta field from post_meta custom field

Tags: custom-post-types

So far I have this. What I am trying to do is to calculate total value of two fields in certain CPT. After that, I would like to update that total value field to all users. I know that need to pass all user id's to the author parameter but struggling. Possible somehow? Thanks in advance.

```
$users = get_users();

    $current_id = get_current_user_id();


        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'tip', 
                  'posts_per_page' => -1,
                  'author' => $current_id,
                 );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $the_query->the_post(); 
                    $roi = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'nasnoviroi', true) ;
                    $total += (float)$roi;
    } // end while

            foreach ($users as $user) {
                update_user_meta($user->ID, 'total_roi', $total);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot add something to a non-existent value; The first call would be: `$total += (float)$roi;` This is not possible, so Add/Initialize the variable **`$total = 0;`** before your $the_query loop.